# Using two handlers for a GraphQL project; handle query with the second one if the first one is not capable of

Tags: go, graphql

I'm trying to use both [SuperGraph as-a-library](https://github.com/dosco/super-graph/) and [GqlGen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen).

So I have two handlers:

1. the first one is **SuperGraph**; this checks that it can carry out the operation
2. the second one is **GqlGen**; this checks that it can carry out the operation if the first one can't

The code I'm using is this:

```golang
type reqBody struct {
    Query string `json:"query"`
}

func Handler(sg *core.SuperGraph, next http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))

        var rBody reqBody
        err = json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes)).Decode(&rBody)

        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), core.UserIDKey, "user_id")
        res, err := sg.GraphQL(ctx, rBody.Query, nil)
        if err == nil {
            render.JSON(w, r, res) // go-chi "render" pkg
        } else {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Post("/graphql", Handler(supergraph, gqlgen))
    })
}
```

#### QUESTIONS

1. Can I avoid these lines at all?

   ```golang
     bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
     r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(bodyBytes))
   ```
2. Is there a better way to handle all this?
3. I know I can use a GraphQL gateway to join multiple schemas under the same endpoint, but is it really worth it? **Is my idea/code really bad?**